# Solution to Partial Differential Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Is there a name for the following partial differential equation?
$$(\nabla V) \cdot (\nabla V) = c$$
Is it known what type of scalar fields $V$ satisfy this? In two dimensions wolfram claims the solution is just $f(x,y) = c_1 x + c_x y.$ Can this be shown for arbitrairly higher dimensions?

Intuitively, for $A= \nabla V$, we have $A^2 = c.$ So the vector field of $A$ has constant magnitude. Perhaps, then, the only possible "change in $A$" would be due to the "curling" $\nabla \times A.$ But if $A=\nabla V$, then $\nabla \times A =0$.

Comment: Have a look at eikonal equations.

Comment: @Aruralreader thanks, that is what I was looking for. I guess my question then is: what are the solutions in the case of constant $c$?

Comment: For constants $a, c_1, \dots,c_n$ with $c_1^2 + \cdots + c_n^2 = c^2$,
$V := a + c_1x_1 + \cdots + c_n x_n$ satisfies $\nabla V\cdot\nabla V = c^2$.

Comment: @Aruralreader is it basic to prove that this is the unique solution?